# Bluetooth Communication using C# in Windows Forms apps in windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bluetooth

Developing a WPF application using C# (.NET Framework 4.5)

I need to use native libraries (No 32Feet.NET suggestions please) to show the list of devices connected via bluetooth and then i need to identify respective COM port numbers.

I know that i can read COM ports using System.IO.Ports & System.ManagementObject namespaces once the device is connected via bluetooth.

The problem is, how to get the list of devices paired to desktop machine using Microsoft libraries?

Comment: Prettty sure there are 3 managed Bluetooth libraries in .NET.  Why native?

Comment: I cannot use third party but managed works for me. Can you please help me to know which managed libraries we have? I have not found any which works in Windows 7.